# JavaMail and Gmail - Permanent allow my app to send mails

Tags: android, security, permissions, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail to send my bug reports... Everything is working, but Gmail is saying, that some strange app (my app) tried to send mail... I then have to click a link and start the app again, afterwards this app is allowed to send mails...

What happens, if I send my app to other users? Will their sending attempts all fail? Is there a difference between a market app and a normal app? Between a signed app and a not signed?

Comment: are you using the same account that's configured on the device??

Comment: no, I've created a gmail account for my app and using this to send reports... Actually, until now, I just read many statements that it's not possible to send mails from the devices owner mail, only if he's once allowing it by offering his credentials... wouldn't mind using the devices mail account, if that's possible so easy..

Answer (score 0):

Then try this:

```
public void envioEmail(final String from, final String mailhost, final String user, final String password, final Boolean auth, final String destinatario, final String assunto, final String mensagem) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            if (mailhost != null) props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailhost);
            if (auth) props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            Authenticator authh = new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                }
            };
            javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props, authh);
            javax.mail.Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            try {
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                msg.setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(destinatario));
                msg.setSubject(assunto);
                msg.setSentDate(new Date());
                msg.setText(mensagem);

                SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport(ssl ? "smtps" : "smtp");
                try {
                    if (auth){
                        t.connect(mailhost, user, password);
                        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                    }else{
                        t.connect();
                        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                    }
                } finally {
                    t.close();
                }
                flag = true;
                atualizaTelaConexao("E-Mail enviado com sucesso!", ctx);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                flag = false;
                atualizaTelaConexao("Erro ao enviar E-Mail! Verifique as configuracoes de e-mail", ctx);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I don't have problems of this form.. Maybe this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("dipakkeshariya@android.com", "dipakkeshariya");
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dipak.keshariya@android.com"));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("dipak.keshariya@mobileappdeveloper.com"));
                    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                    message.setContent("Hi Dipak Keshariya (Android Developer)", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

                    Transport.send(message);

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And see below link for more information.

[Android – Send Email Via GMail (Actually Via SMTP)](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually.html)